# sum numbers in mysql with multi digits after the comma

Tags: mysql, sum

I have numbers in MySQL like this

```
549.97
550.565
395.815
315.9
and so on
```

and when I run the query sum

```
select 549.97 + 550.565 + 395.815 + 315.9
```

I got this result

```
 1812.250
```

which is not correct

and that's because the numbers after the comma are sometimes one and sometimes two and sometimes three ..

How could I let the numbers be correct with sum when I have one or two or three numbers after the comma in MySQL

And this is my query in the table

```
select sum(voucher_amount) from vouchers where voucher_amount > 0
```

I always get wrong number 
even when I try round like

```
select round(sum(voucher_amount),2) from vouchers where voucher_amount > 0
```

because there are numbers with only one digits after the comma

Comment: Can you share sample data and required result

Comment: What output you want exactly?

Comment: `549.97 + 550.565 + 395.815 + 315.9 is 1812.25` which is equivalent to `1812.250` so how Can you say that this is not correct?

Comment: It's perfectly correct - although I've no idea why you'd want to add constants in MySQL.

Comment: i have table called vouchers and there is column called voucher_amount i need to sum the voucher_amount so i wrote this select sum(voucher_amount) from vouchers where voucher_amount > 0 now i always gat the wrong value because the digits after the comma sometimes there is only one digit and sometime there is tow and sometimes three i need to gat only three digits after the comma with correct answer thanks

Comment: What comma there is no comma in the question?

Comment: sorry i mean dot . like 5.555 and 5.55 and 5.5 and so on

Comment: @AwarPulldozer I update my answer.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense at all. You are claiming that your sum is not correct because of some dot logic (which only you understand and 24 ppl which saw this question didn't) but you're wrong. If you wanted your result to be written in 2 decimal spaces then write that as your question. Maybe you wanted result without additional zeros at the end of decimal number. Since we can't provide solution for problem which can't be explained this question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TRUNCATE Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate), try this:

```
select TRUNCATE( sum(voucher_amount) , 2 ) from vouchers where voucher_amount > 0
```

It seems to be true.